# Как сделать, чтобы при переходе по ссылке отобразился маркер на карте?

Tags: google-maps

Как мне реализовать в Google Maps такое же поведение, как здесь?
[Яндекс.Карты: Вывод списка объектов карты](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/object_list)

Мне нужно, чтобы при клике по ссылке отобразился маркер на карте.
Спасибо заранее.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вопрос наверное уже не актуален,но может кому понадобится.

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&key=your_api_key_here"></script>
```

Получение ключа: [API KEY GOOGLE](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key)

> Код  JavaScript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var geocoder;
var map;
var query = new Array('Красная Площадь, Красная площадь, Москва, Россия', 'Триумфальная пл., 2, Москва, Россия', 'ул. Маросейка, 9/2, стр. 1, Москва, Россия'); //Адреса на карте
var idArr = new Array('marker1','marker2','marker3');

function initialize() {
  geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 15
  }
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
  codeAddress();
}

function codeAddress() {
    for (var i = 0; i < query.length; i++) {
        var address = query[i];
        geocoder.geocode({
                'address': address
            }, function(k) {
                return function(results, status) {
                    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                        var a = document.getElementById(idArr[k]);
                        a.onclick = function() {
                            map.setZoom(17);
                            map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
                        }
                        map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
                        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                            map: map,
                            position: results[0].geometry.location
                        });
                    } else {
                        alert('Геокод не был успешным по следующей причине: ' + status);
                    }
                }
            }(i)
        );
    }
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
 </script>
```

> HTML

```
<body>
    <div id="map-canvas"  style="width: 600px; height: 400px"></div>
    <div class="maps-marker">
        <a href="#!" id="marker1">Красная площадь</a>
        <a href="#!" id="marker2">Театр Сатиры</a>
        <a href="#!" id="marker3">Макдоналдс</a>
    </div>
</body>
```

> Результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]